# Android Tesseract OCR with NDK (c++)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ocr, tesseract

Is it possible to use google tesseract OCR in android through NDK?

So I have some C++ code which uses tesseract OCR and now I don't want to move it to Android because it is connected with code that uses openCV and I have this in c++.

Many thanks for advice and links and how can I use it and build it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most certainly possible to use the Tesseract OCR library in your own Android application through the NDK. However,  you will have to compile the Tesseract library along with another library called Leptonica Image Processing Library and they take considerable amount of time to compile.

A guy named Robert Theis created a GitHub project (named [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two)) that would allow you to call the Tesseract API using Java through the Android Java Native Interface (JNI). You can read a bit more about that [here](https://droidcomp.wordpress.com/2012/08/04/building-the-tesseract-ndk-library-for-android/).

I recommend you to follow [this](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) particular tutorial written by Gautam Gupta on how to set things up.

On the same page of that tutorial, there's also an explanatory [comment](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/#comment-184181) giving you a step-by-step list of instructions you need to follow in order to configure the Tesseract OCR library with your Android application in Android Studio.

Edit: The comment URL doesn't always seem to go directly to the comment, so the comment to look for is from user Matz (April 21, 2015) and starts with "*For ANDROID STUDIO developers, here’s what I did on my Windows 8.1 machine.*"